# Using jagged list for only two indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, list, jagged-arrays

I have an application which is using about 5 different "list of lists", but I am only using index 0 or index 1.

Is this bad practice or will it lead to poor performance?

Here is an example I made similiar to what I'm doing:

```
internal class Program
{
    private const int Count = 64;
    private static int _index;
    private static List<List<int>> _data = new List<List<int>>();
    private static List<List<int>> _dataprevious = new List<List<int>>();
    private static List<List<double>> _datacalculated = new List<List<double>>();
    private static Random _rand = new Random();

    private static void GetData(object o)
    {
        //Clear list and add new data
        _data[_index].Clear();
        _datacalculated[_index].Clear();
        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            _data[_index].Add(_rand.Next(4500, 5500));
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            _datacalculated[_index].Add(_data[_index][i]/4.78);
        }
        //Output data to console
        Console.WriteLine(_index + ":");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", _data[_index]));
        Console.WriteLine();
        //Switch between index 0 and 1
        _index = 1 - _index;
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        //Setup lists
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            _data.Add(new List<int>());
            _dataprevious.Add(new List<int>());
            _datacalculated.Add(new List<double>());
        }
        //Get new data every 5 seconds
        new Timer(GetData, null, 0, 5000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be fine, don't waste efforts optimizing too early, optimize only when a performance concern is concretized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will it lead to poor performance

Performance is relative. Here, the other operations that you are doing totally dominate the (few) list accesses. If you cache `_data[_index]` (and others) in local variables then you will face one list access per 64 iterations which is nothing.

You can definitively answer this question by profiling the code. But back of the envelope calculations such as the the in the previous paragraph are also valid and can save some time.